# add user control dynamically

Tags: asp.net

i have a page a three buttons, when user clicks 1st control i want to display 1st user control, for button2 second user control and so on... how can i achieve this in page_init as we dont knw which button got clicked

Comment: Why do you want to add them dynamically? Make them visible according to the button that was clicked and hide the others in the Button_Click event handler.

Comment: coz this will make my page very heavy

Comment: @user685663: dynamic controls are making your life much more "heavier". You shouldn't do that when you don't need, because it gets a lot more difficult for example with ViewState and Event-handling issues. Besides, controls that aren't visible, won't be rendered as HTML by ASP.Net at all, hence your page isn't "heavier" at all.

Comment: Tim thnx for ur feedback.. can u pls provide some detailed information of using user controls once rather than dynamic control.. as u stated viewstate and eventhandling issue.. is it true to add control once and hide them is not goin to give me a performance issue

Comment: @user685663: here is the answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304032/asp-net-dynamic-load-controls-vs-visible-true/1304117#1304117

Comment: thnx tim... ur answer is correct.. how can i mark it correct?

Comment: @user685663: added these comments as answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the button ID with this trick in Page_Init event

```
string buttonID = Request["__EVENTTARGET"].ToString();
```

In buttonID in buttonID variable you will find the client ID of the button..

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to display them.

It is easier to have the controls hidden when not needed and only visible when required.

If you want to add them dynamically the easiest way to add them is to add the control to a placeholder when you need them.
eg

ASP

```
   <asp:PlaceHolder id="myPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Code behind (C#)

```
myControl = new UserControl();
myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(myControl);
```

But you also need to remember that to be able to access the control on postback you need to re-add it on submit/postback.

Comment: now i am bit confused... i thought i have 5 user controls on page it will be much heavier... so i thought to add the control dynamically which according to @Tim Schmelter is not so...

Comment: Its something I recomend you try it for your self.
It can be a right pain in the a** to deal with dynalicly added controls but may solve the problem you have.