# Asp.net: conditional loading of user controls fails

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Hello (sorry for the poor title)

I have a user control which loads different additional user controls based on some conditions like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SubPage.ascx.cs" Inherits="SubPage" %>
<%@ Register Src="<srcA>" TagName="A" TagPrefix="CTRL" %>
<%@ Register Src=">srcB>" TagName="B" TagPrefix="CTRL" %>

<% if (someValue == 1) { %>
    Loading user control A..
    <CTRL:A runat="server" />
<% } else { %>
    Loading user control B..
    <CTRL:B runat="server" />
<% } %>
```

The result will look correct; the expected content is displayed. But I noticed that even though *someValue != 1* and control B is displayed, control A is still loaded behind the scenes (page load is called).

Why is this? And what would be a better approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page_Load is called because you handle this event. 
Don't try to load them in this way but use the Visible-Property instead from codebehind.

Expose a public function that the controller(in your case `SubPage.ascx`)  calls after it changed the visible state to load the content of the UserControl. Controls that aren't visible won't be rendered as html at all.

Loading controls dynamically if you don't really need can cause unnecessary ViewState- or Event-Handling issues. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304032/asp-net-dynamic-load-controls-vs-visible-true/1304117#1304117) are some other disadvantages mentioned regarding dynamic UserControls.

Comment: Thanks, I will follow your advice.

Comment: Page_Load will still be called on both controls though, right?

Comment: @kappasums: If you don't handle the Page_Load-Event in your UserControl, then it won't be called. Normally you don't need to make your UserControl dependent on any Page-Event but it should be controlled by the page("expose a public function...").

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `LoadControl` method instead

```
<% if (someValue == 1) { %>
Loading user control A..  

Page.LoadControl(("~\ExampleUserControl_A.ascx");

<% } else { %>
    Loading user control B..
    this.LoadControl(("~\ExampleUserControl_B.ascx");
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But as the others has made me aware of the complications with view state, I will go with their approach.

Answer (score 0):

Code Front:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SubPage.ascx.cs" Inherits="SubPage" %>
<%@ Register Src="<srcA>" TagName="A" TagPrefix="CTRL" %>
<%@ Register Src="<srcB>" TagName="B" TagPrefix="CTRL" %>
<asp:placeholder id="plhControls" runat="server" />
```

Code Behind:

```
if (someValue == 1) { 
    CTRLA ctrlA = (CTRLA)LoadControl("~/Controls/ctrlA.ascx");
    plhControls.Controls.Add(ctrlA);
} else {
    CTRLB ctrlB = (CTRLB)LoadControl("~/Controls/ctrlB.ascx");
    plhControls.Controls.Add(ctrlB);
}
```